# SSIS aggregate based on select fields

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to use the aggregate functionality in SSIS to remove duplicates from a flat file.  I have a pipe delimited text file which should contain unique records.  The unique qualifiers are model and year.  I can only have one model number per year.  When I try to use the aggregate I can set it you to filter on this criteria and it limits the record count as I would expect.  However, the results need to include the other 20 fields that are in the original file.  When I include all of the fields in the aggregate function, I am fine as long as the second record is identical to the original record.  What I am looking to do essentially is to identify a duplicate based on model and year and to not import either record.  Ideally I would like to write these records to a separate table so that I can report the duplicate.  One step at a time though.  How can I identify the duplicate based on 2 fields in a record and still import all 22 into the database?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by importing ALL records in the flat file to a staging table.

Then call a stored procedure that uses `ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY ()` to get the entire first row of each Model/Year duplicate and insert it to the destination table, and use the same logic to move the duplicates to a duplicate-reporting table.